# How does 8051 distinguish byte address from bit address?

Tags: 8051

How does 8051 distinguish byte address from bit address? For example, the byte address of TMOD is 0x89, but the bit address of the IE0 is also 0x89. Will this cause conflict?

I am looking forward to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about context. Just imagine, the only thing the 8051 ever "sees" are numbers. If a number is a command-code, an address, a bit-mask, data, .... just depends on the state of the 8051 at any given moment in time.

The TMOD is register. It can be access via an address.

The IE0 is a bit/flag. It can be "inside" the TCON register.

Microprocessor coding is super-much fun but you will have to develop a whole special mindset for it and really dive into it. Get the 8051 reference manual and actually understand it: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc4316.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. The distinction between a bit address and byte address is given by the instruction type. Only the following bit instructions use bit addressing

```
CLR  bit
SETB bit
CPL  bit
JB   bit, target
JNB  bit, target
JBC  bit, target
MOV  C,bit
MOV  bit,C
ORL  C,bit
ORL  C,/bit
ANL  C,bit
ANL  C,/bit
XRL  C,bit
```

All other instruction use byte address.

`bit` address is then mapped to internal data memory range or SFR registers. In case of SFR registers only registers with address with low 3 bits equal to zero are bit addressable. Look at next picture. Left column is byte address of SFR and only some registers is bit addresable (`P0`, `TCON`, `P1`, `SCON`, `P2`, `IE`, `P3`, `IP`, `PSW`, `ACC`, `B`)

For example `P0` is mapped to bit address like this: (last row on the image)

```
P0.0 0x80
P0.1 0x81
P0.2 0x82
P0.3 0x83
P0.4 0x84
P0.5 0x85
P0.6 0x86
P0.7 0x87
```

[image: bit address mapping to SFR address]

So bit address `0x89` is not `TMOD`, but `TCON.1` what is also defined as `IE0`

More about bit addressing you can read [here](https://what-when-how.com/8051-microcontroller/bit-addresses-for-io-and-ram/)